# Camera plugin phonegap allowing none image files

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am using phonegap camera plugin in android and it launches gallary to pick file. but here I am able to pick none image file also. How to restrict this. 
This happening only when I have installed third party file explorers.

Comment: So you want to select an image OR you want to restrict from selecting an image?

Comment: i only want to allow select image.